# Why can't I change my icon theme in gnome-classic?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, themes, icons, gnome-classic

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 (updated) and gnome-classic (I missed it :3)
I've tried setting my icon theme, GTK theme, and window theme in gnome-tweak-tool, as well as Ubuntu Tweak, gconf-editor, and dconf-editor. Even though it shows my selections are selected, the icons and themes stay the same.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:**

I've tested things out on gnome-shell and Unity, and I have full control over icons and such in those environments, but still no control in gnome-classic. I would really like to figure this out.

**Update 2:**

It seems that after uninstalling Unity that I have full control over everything. Any explanation (since Unity or some part of it seemed to be the cause) would be really nice.

Comment: I seem to be able to do this using the latest (v0.6) of ubuntu-tweak.  What have you tried?

Comment: When I hadn't uninstalled unity, I had tried using ubuntu-tweak as well. It did nothing.

Comment: are you sure that the icon theme installed correctly or you have the right directory?

Comment: You should probably post Update 2 as an answer below and accept it so we know there's a solution to this. If a better solution comes along later, then you can switched the accepted status to that one instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OP Fixed it by himself:

> It seems that after uninstalling Unity that I have full control over everything. Any explanation (since Unity or some part of it seemed to be the cause) would be really nice.

Any answers on how it happened will be voted  up